# 1st phrase. Help me please to read old german writings?

Tags: history, handwriting

The writings are pretty old: 1912, 1913.

That are the writing on the back cover of an old clock. So probably the writings might be about the works being done on it and who did this works, or about the place where this work was done or maybe the writings about the place where this clock was or being presented etc... I do not know German language at all...[image][image][image: First letter is “H”, the last is some strange letter because it is also on the end of some other words on other writings][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

I’m sorry again for maybe duplicating something. I add the whole view of the back cover. As I understand the writings with no dates belong to four different people. If it is possible to read it I will add them word by word.

You already helped me a lot!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: What a scrawl. All I can decipher is Würzburg, probably the city this was built in

Comment: It’s made in Berlin and it’s 18th century clock... It has 5 more writings but others are even more difficult to decipher and has no dates...

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54571/2-help-me-please-to-read-old-german-writings

Comment: Welcome on the site! Please edit your post from your original account (if you are the editor). Your edit suggestion to the question would be only okay, if it was done by you. But the reviewers can't decide it, if you edit your own question from a different account.

Comment: Please use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged, so you can freely edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is:

> Alter ..., gekauft (ge..ft pretty certain)  in Würzburg im (Name des Geschäfts, Hertie?), 1912

translating to "Old (possibly name of the clock type, picture of whole item would help), bought (?) in Würzburg (Name of town) in (possibly name of shop, possibly 'Hertie').

Hertie is an old shop chain established by *Her*mann *Tie*tze.

Comment: *Altes Werk gekauft  in Würzburg im Hertie, 1912*. Old clockwork bought in Würzburg at Hertie, 1912. That's a clockmaker's notice. The clock was repaired at least once.

Comment: The W from presumed Werk looks a lot different than the W in Würzburg though

Comment: The last "in" looks like a "im" to me

Comment: The letter at the beginning of *Werk* can't be a Kurrent S, because the next curve is not a valid letter. It must belong to the previous one, making it a Kurrent W. My guess is the W of *Würzburg* was accidentally begun as a Kurrent *w* and then, given there is no way to correct ink on wood, was finished as an Antiqua W.

Comment: I agree with Janka for the most part, but am fairly sure the last word before the year is "Herbst", i.e. autumn.