# 2nd phrase. Help me please to read old german writings?

Tags: history, handwriting

The writings are pretty old: 1912, 1913 and earlier I guess...

That are the writing on the back cover of an old clock. So probably the writings might be about the works being done on it and who did this works, or about the place where this work was done or maybe the writings about the place where this clock was or being presented etc... I do not know German language at all...

It is gigantic musical astronomical clock made in Berlin between 1780-1789.

I’m trying to find out any of it’s history by deciphering this writings!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7uFw.jpg)[image: enter image description here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qRik.jpg)![enter image description here][image][image][image][image]
[image][image]

I added the whole view of all writings together. Only two of them has dates.

As I can see personally the writings before those with dates should belong to four different people. I’m very sorry for my stupid behavior and confused answering, that is because I feel a little bit complicated with using this forum. It’s a little bit strange for me.

You already helped a lot with deciphering. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!![image][image][image]

If it is possible please unlock the answers which were before... sorry again for not good understanding how to use you forum... THANK YOU!

Comment: Please do not double post the same question. Instead, go back to your first question and edit it to improve it. Thank you.

Comment: @Takkat das ist aber ein anderer Satz als der in der anderen Frage. Ob er auf derselben Uhr ist oder nicht, ist nach den Bildern her schwer zu beurteilen. Die Kommentare von Janka und mir mit unvollständigen Lösungsvorschlägen zu löschen, halte ich daher für unangebracht.

Comment: Please modify the other question instead. It already has an answer, so that one is the question we will keep.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: die Frage wurde erst **nach** dem Schließen komplett neu umgeschrieben und enthält jetzt tatsächlich verwertbar mehr Kontext. Antworten die nur in Kommentaren gegeben werden [sind ausdrücklich unerwünscht](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Derartige Fragen sollte man als Community Wiki beantworten, dann kann jeder etwas beitragen und muss nicht die Kommentare dazu bemühen.

Comment: Both questions are about an old writing on a clock... is makes little sense to keep both of them. I closed the previous question as a dupe to be able to keep this more elaborate answer in the end. All additions should go as an [edit] to this question, and answers should be given as a Community Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

That's also German. I read Zum 13ten Jebw 1913 f.l. Franz … … Curt von Arnim. – For the 13th birthday for dear Franz … … Curt von Arnim. I guess "Jebw" is meant as an abbreviation vor Geburtstag in Berlin dialect. As Curt von Arnim was long dead in 1913, we could only guess Franz was one of his great-great-grandchildren, nephews or such. – Janka

*(Two of the previous comments have been restored and transformed into this comunity wiki, but some are missing. My text below hardly makes sense without the missing part, so I re-tell it from memory.)*
I'm convinced that what Janka reads as "Jebw" is instead "Julius", the month Juli/July in its Latin version.
*(The German text below is my answer to Janka's question doubting my interpretation.)*

Zu jener Zeit hat man das "u" nicht schön sauber "schüsselförmig" rund wie heute geschrieben, sondern mehr als Zickzack-Linie. Deshalb wurde damals auch oft über dem kleinen u eine gebogene Linie gezogen, um das "u" vom "n" zu unterscheiden (ansonsten sahen die beiden Buchstaben in Handschrift nahezu gleich aus). Ob dieser Zusatzbogen aber gemacht wurde oder nicht, war individuell vom Schreiber abhängig. Die erste Aufwärtsspitze hinter der Schleife müsste da "i" sein, dessen Punkt weiter hinten ist (aber unter Berücksichtigung des schrägen Schriftwinkels durchaus "auf" dem i sitzt). – Volker Landgraf